# Restoring Default Layout in Rider

Tags: rider, jetbrains-rider

I recently lost that Toolbar item in Rider where you select the project to run and configurations for it. I finally found it again, but it is now on the left hand side above solution explorer.

I'd like it all to be how it was when I first installed Rider.

I have tried to select Restore Default Layout from the Windows menu, but that appears to be a no-op (it does nothing).

Can anyone help. Is there the equivalent of a factory reset?

Comment: If you mean that it is now a new UI that disturbs your workflow, then you can switch to the old one via `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | New UI`.
Or you can fix it by moving Run widget to the right side in Settings `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars` -> Toolbar -> Left Side or Right side -> Run/Debug Widget

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the built-in command `Restore default settings` ([see official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reset_Settings.html#restore-defaults)) or (backup and) delete the content of `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\Rider2023.1` (assuming you're on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by moving Run widget to the right side in Settings `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars`[image]